# Maven build for Stanford CoreNLP and Stanford Parser

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Given that coreNLP is almost 1gb and Stanford Parser (as provided on the [Stanford website](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Download)) is 300+mb, is it necessary to include both in my classpath if I am running both in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all the demo functions provided in the Stanford demo code work just fine with the following maven dependencies and nothing else. Stanford corenlp is a behemoth, but the stanford-parser is just a small jar of classes. The models from core-nlp jar work with stanford-parser.

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-parser -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```